# Play mp3 file by clicking at the word

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to play a certain file when clicking on a word.

Something like that

```
   <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor <span class="word2play" id="sit">sit</span> amet, consectetur adipiscing <span class="word2play" id="elit">elit</span>, sed do eiusmod tempor"<p>
```

I can catch the click, get id, but I do not know how to play mp3 file without player.

Comment: Use the [`audio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) element. Set the `src` when the word is clicked and `play()`

Comment: One audio element for all word?

Comment: Yes. Just change the `src` dynamically

Comment: I can use style="display: none" for audio element and it works just fine. Thank you.

Comment: @Alex if your question is solved with the help from the comments, please consider closing or deleting it. It is very unlikely that you will get further answers.